# InDesign Scripting how to quit application (not document)

Tags: vbscript, extendscript, jsx, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to automate data merge process. Here's what I have:

First of all have created a working datamerge script:

```
function main(){
    mySnippet ();
    myTeardown();
}
//<setup>
//<snippet>
function mySnippet(){
// automate datamerge
var myDocument = app.open(File("P:/RxCut/In Design Implementation/build/automate/automate.indd"));
var myDataSource = File("P:/RxCut/In Design Implementation/build/automate/automate.txt");


myDocument.dataMergeProperties.selectDataSource(myDataSource);
myDocument.dataMergeProperties.mergeRecords();
myDocument=myDocument.save("P:/RxCut/In Design Implementation/build/automate/AutomatedMerged.indd");
app.activeDocument.save(new File("P:/RxCut/In Design Implementation/build/automate/AutomatedMerged2.indd"));
myDocument.close();
}


//</snippet>
//<teardown>
function myTeardown(){
}
```

This runs great as expected!

Then had to write a vbscript to open InDesign and run that jsx script above:

```
Set myInDesign = CreateObject("InDesign.Application.CS5")
Msgbox("This message from Vbscript")

myJavaScript = "C:\test2.jsx"

myInDesign.DoScript myJavaScript, 1246973031
```

Now if `CreateObject("InDesign.Application.CS5")` opens InDesign how to close it?

Comment: according to [Indesign Scripting Reference](http://indesignscriptingreference.com/cs2/vbscript-cs2/application-3.htm) CS2's `Application` object had a `Quit` method. Have you tried that? (ie `myInDesign.Quit`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.quit();
```

easy as that

> app.open

to open

```
app.quit
```

to quit