# Close an application using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I was trying to open and close an application.
I tried like this:

```
Dim App1 
Set App1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
App1.Run("firefox")
App1.Quit
```

Firefox will open, but it will not close.

Error message:

> object doesn't support this property or method

I referred [InDesign Scripting how to quit application (not document)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602718/indesign-scripting-how-to-quit-application-not-document)

Please tell me the procedure to close the application.

Comment: Can't we close a previously opened application (also opened by VBScript)?                (application running in foreground)

Comment: Quitting a vbscript application would simply be a `Wscript.Quit` - so that part doesn't really apply.  Firefox is not a vbscript application.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be able to terminate a process that way you need to use the `Exec` method instead of the `Run` method.

```
Set ff = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("firefox")
'you do stuff
ff.Terminate
```

Comment: This worked for me. Just wanted to add this since the answer was never excepted, but was my 2nd search hit for "vbscript launch application and shutdown".

Comment: But can't it close the existing application?

Comment: What do you mean "close the existing applications"? It terminates the process that was started via `Exec`.

Comment: It doesn't work in HTA.  What should I do?? Please help.

Comment: @arunpandiyarajhen If that doesn't work in your HTA you're doing something wrong. Please post a new question with a [mcve] of your code and a more detailed problem description.

Answer (score 3):

I observed a few ways:

1. `taskkill` - Worked only if I try to kill the same process, as I run.

   ```
   Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   oShell.Run """C:\My_Scripts\ddl.exe"" -p1 -c"

   'some code

   oShell.Run "taskkill /f /im ddl.exe", , True
   ```
2. `SendKeys` - Works for all app, if the window name is known.

   ```
   Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   filename = "C:\Some_file.txt - Notepad"
   act = oShell.AppActivate(fileName)
   oShell.SendKeys "% C"
   ```
3. WMI object - 2 ways above worked good for me so I didn't try it.
   You can find an example [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/f531dcbd-94c2-411d-abc9-2d846d5b76db/vbs-to-close-all-open-applications?forum=ITCG):

   ```
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
       & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

   Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
       ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Chrome.exe'")

   Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   For Each objProcess in colProcessList
       oShell.Run "taskkill /im chrome.exe", , True
   Next
   ```

Comment: Third method: use in For Each Loop `objProcess.Terminate()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative VBScript implementation:

```vb
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Notepad.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

Comment: [Similar answer here with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232763/129130).

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is not a COM object. There is no Firefox COM object. Firefox does not want you to use COM. Or NET. Or Microsoft. That is why you could not create a Firefox object, so you created a WScript.Shell object instead.

WScript.Shell does not have a quit method. If it did, it wouldn't help kill Firefox.

This is an [example](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_process_stop.htm) of using WMI from VBS to start, then kill a process like Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Good work for this example:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run """C:\My_Scripts\ddl.exe"" -p1 -c"

'some code

oShell.Run "taskkill /f /im ddl.exe", , True
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!