# How to close/terminate/kill an instance of a application with VBS?

Tags: vbscript

How to close/terminate/kill an instance of a application with VBS?

I've tried the following code, suggested on several posts, and it didn´t work.

```
Set x =  GetObject(,"xxx.Application")
x.quit
```

Comment: Try simple `lResult = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("taskkill /f /im MyProcess.exe", 0, True)` to terminate all processes with specified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I used **WMI** at one point, and that worked OK - provided the script runs with the access rights required to kill the processes in question (in other words admin rights for system processes, user rights for user context processes - I suppose there could be [NT Privileges / NT Rights](https://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html) (system wide privileges) and [custom ACL permission](https://superuser.com/a/110202/11906) settings ([access control list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) - attached to objects) involved as well - the configuration of which might vary from site to site):

> ***Note:*** `the below script will kill all Notepad.exe processes! (unless access is denied)`

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Notepad.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

---

***Some Links***:

- **[Close an application using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355332/close-an-application-using-vbscript)** (several other options)
- **[Kill a process which says “Access denied”](https://superuser.com/a/110202/11906)** (auperuser - Terminate Process ACL)
- [Unkillable Processes](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes/)

Comment: Thanks, worked out as required...

Comment: Great. Look out for all those complications. Windows is getting crazier and crazier :-).