# How to close any open file irrespective file type

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I created a function to open any valid file now I want to close the opened file.
Input file could be of any valid file type: .docx, .bmp, xlsx, etc.

I was trying to make `WScript` object and trying to close file using below code, but it's not working.

```
Public Function openfile(filepath)
    Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ws.Run filepath 
    'taking the screen shot of opened file 
End function

Public Function closefile(filepath)
    Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ws.AppActivate (filepath)
    ws.Terminate
End function
```

However, I am unable to close the opened file and getting error. File could be any valid file type which I will get to know only at run time. We already have a function to update the opened file for .txt and Excel.

Can anybody help me to find out how I can close already opened file irrespective of file type?

Comment: Take a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39278494/2784816). You can search Win32_Process based on the CommandLine field where you can provide the filepath.

Comment: thanks for the solution. i am able to close the file. however still facing issue to close pdf file type.